# Is it possible to resolve REST end points of a dependency JAR file in spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a 2 Spring boot jars which work fine as 2 independent applications, however, I have been asked to merge  2 jars into a single application

The easiest thing I thought would be to add app-2 as a maven dependency into app-1 but the problem is that when the app-1 starts it only recognises the app-1  REST endpoints but ignores REST endpoint of app-2 altogether.

I was hoping that when the app-1 starts it will automatically pick the endpoints declared in app-2

```
@RestController
Class2{

@GetMapping(/hello-from-app2)
public String myapp2(){
  return "HELLO FROM APP2"
}
```

This code gets ignored and at server start up I can only see the endpoints exposed by app-1 are visible.

Comment: Make sure app-2's base package is configured to be scanned.

Comment: what is base package for app-1 and app-2? NOTE: It is possible to scan even if app-1 and app-2 having different base packages

Answer (score 2):

If you are including App2.jar as a dependency into App1.jar, the best approach would be to import the Configuration of App2. **If you start adding scans and stuff you would be tightly coupling you App1 to your App2.** App1 would have to know implementation details of App2 that doesn't need to.

If you just import the configuration of App2, the configuration details would remain encapsulated.

I assume you have a Java Config class (or an XML Config file) for App1 and another one for App2. I also assume that the config of App2 contains all the necessary annotations for component scanning and the correct base-packages.

If that's the case, you can add an import like this and it should work right away:

```
@Configuration
@Import(SpringConfigurationApp2.class)
public class SpringConfigurationApp1 {

//... some beans....

}
```

Comment: Spring boot provides autoconfiguration so I don't have any configuration class, did you mean import the main class of app2?

Comment: You should create a Configuration class then for App1. The Import annotation will accept any class that's annotated as @Configuration. This include main classes of Spring Boot Applications. Checkout the answer provided by Shaunak. It is also a very nice approach. Both of these are valid and you should apply the one that better suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I saw answer provided by @Diego but with that user need to make changes in client application. (ex. `@Import(SpringConfigurationApp2.class)` here).

I have another approach where client (App-1) does not need to make any change in application. It will just work seamlessly. This approach is by use of spring's auto configuration and same feature is used by spring-boot dependency.

Here is my answer to achieve using autoconfiguration.

For App-2,

1)  create `spring.factories` file under resources/META-INF

2) Add `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
path-to-app-2-application/SpringConfigurationApp2`

For App-1,
  Just include App-2 as maven dependency and you are Done.

Here is a link to get more information about https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-spring-boot-auto-configuration.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've been travelling and wasn't able to answer. OP didn't mention that changes weren't allowed. But this is a very nice approach.